# Does JQuery works on all the buttons with same ID (different pages)

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I need to use JQuery to call vb function through function

```
$("[id*=Button1]").click();
```

I have many `Button1` on both sub and master.

My JQuery is on sub content page. I wonder if it actually trigger the button1 on both master and sub content page?

Thanks very much!

Comment: What gets sent to the browser is an evaluation of master page with the specific content page inside. jQuery will look over the whole document with `$("[id*=Button1]")`, so **any** match will be triggered - the browser has no idea about master/content pages

Comment: so is there a way that I can make it call one button only (without giving buttons on different page different names)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery will act on the entire rendered HTML. It makes no difference whether the HTML originated in a "master" or a "content" page on the server. If the HTML shows up on the client as a single page (as opposed to say, an `<iframe>`), JQuery will act on it.

On a side note, you should do your best to keep the "id" property of each HTML element unique. That's the way it's designed to be, and you should do yourself a long-term favor by observing that basic rule.

JQuery has lots and lots of selector rules, and I'm sure you can find some way of applying those selector rules to select the correct button. See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ to get started. But using selectors creatively is much better than using the same `id` for different elements.

Comment: so is there a way that I can make it call one button only (without giving buttons on different page different names)? As i currently have 12 button1 unfortunately

Comment: As I mention above, give them different ids, even if that means going back and changing things.

Comment: I agree with Ken. There might be a way to do this, but you shouldn't. IDs should be unique. Your HTML is invalid if you have non-unique IDs.

Comment: I see, if it's the only way.. My IDs for buttons are unique on the same page, but for my 12 pages, I have a "button1" in each page which call a different sql stored procedure... I think I will change teh IDs . Thanks!